# Axios returns Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have a Laravel app in which I use axios in a VueJS component to send GET requests to an external public API upon clicking a button, but it throws these error:

```
[Error] Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (random, line 0)
```

Here is my failed attempt:

```
const url = "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random";
const response = await axios.get(url);
```

I just should receive some Chuck Norris jokes to print on the console...

PS: I've seen some facts relative to CORS but I didn't get anything out of it, so here I am.

Comment: axios does not set that header by default. However Laravel does have the line `window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';` somewhere. You should remove that. It's generally bad practice

Comment: Ok, I'll look for it right now! But... Why is it a bad practice and so why Laravel uses it?

Comment: Well the story is that: (1) That header was sent by jQuery.ajax (2) Laravel sets it because server-side legacy code uses `Request::isAjax` a lot which relied on that header existing. It's bad practice because (1) `XMLHttpRequest` is not the only request that we might use to do ajax, axios might wrap around `XMLHttpRequest` for now but there's also `fetch` (2) The server should not care if the request is coming in as AJAX or from some other place.

Comment: Did you create your API in laravel?  If you create api in laravel than you need to create a cross middleware  for it.

Comment: I haven't created an API: it is a function called when clicking a button.

Comment: I commented out the line pointed b y @apokryfos, that is the same of deleting the headers just before the request but obviously nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel uses a header to be able to determine wether a request was XHR or a normal request.

In the source code of Laravel you can see the [`Request::ajax()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L233) method, which calls the [`isXmlHttpRequest()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L1724) method from Symfony.

The only issue with this is that CORS doesn't really like such headers.

If you want to remove it, check `bootstrap.js` in `resources/js` and compile your assets again.

Another solution would be to delete the header just before the call:

`delete axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];`

Comment: Just did it with no success. And the first error changed too (the others are unchanged): Request header field X-CSRF-TOKEN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Comment: Great, that means that it did actually work, but you have to remove the X-CSRF-TOKEN header as well. So basically the same: `delete axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'];`. Also, if I recall correctly you can transform the request by using the parameter like this: `transformRequest(data, headers) { delete axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN']; delete axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With']; return data; }`

Comment: It worked! You made my day :D it was the first time facing this problem and it seemed very time-consuming to troubleshoot. Thank you so much! I will mark your answer as helpful!